# Why express app.render loads images with local file path synchronously? - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image, express, asynchronous

I noticed the following:

- When I want to render an array of image **URLs hosted in another website** like this:

**index.js**

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/sample', function(err, db) {
    db.collection('collSample').findOne( { somevar: 'somevalue'  }, function(err, doc) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        res.render('index', { 
          title: 'render images' , 
          imagesPaths: doc.images.`**URLs**`
        });
        db.close();
    });
});
```

**index.jade**

```
- each path in imagesPaths
    span
        img(src="#{path}")
```

I get this Network info from Chrome Developer Tools. Notice how the images are being rendered **asynchronously**
[image: As you can see, images are loading asynchronously]

- But, if I use images **stored localy** like this:

**index.js**

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/sample', function(err, db) {
    db.collection('collSample').findOne( { somevar: 'somevalue'  }, function(err, doc) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        res.render('index', { 
          title: 'render images' , 
          imagesPaths: doc.images.`**localPath**`
        });
        db.close();
    });
});
```

**index.jade**

```
- each path in imagesPaths
    span
        img(src="#{path}")
```

I get this Network info. Note that iamges are being rendered **synchronously**. Also, **load time is considerably lower**.
[image]

**Question 1**: How can I force rendering images asynchronously?

**Question 2**: Why sometimes nodejs renders images async and others sync? I thought that nodejs will render a bunch of images asynchronously, regardless of what is inside of image src attribute.

Comment: Node.js doesn't render the images. Your browser does.

Comment: You're both totally right @Cristy. This seems to be the reason why images stay in queue, extracted from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing): _Chrome enforces a maximum of six TCP connections per host_,

Comment: yes, unless you use HTTP/2

Answer (score 1):

1. They are **not loaded synchronously**. All the requests are made async, (see that all the white rectangles begin to be printed at the same time).

The real difference stands in the path of the request towards the resource location:

- every **remote request** get through the Internet and it is not guaranteed that the arrival order is the same at the start.
- every **local request** is processed **quite immediately**, giving the illusion to be sync, quite preserving the order of the requests too.

**Proof:** Try add the local path of avery huge image o(N*10MB) or o(100MB) (for example http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/hs-2015-02-a-hires_jpg.jpg ) in the middle of the array and see that the image is finishes to be load last.